# vboxnet shows wrong traffic count

Tags: linux, virtualbox, traffic

I'm a little bit confused in traffic count between virtual machine (using VirtualBox on Linux x86, 3.2.0).

Internet access from virtual machine is through NAT (iptables). VM using host only adapter, e.g. `vboxnet1`. After some downloading/uploading from VM (about 2 GB), I see these:

```
vboxnet1  Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 0a:00:27:00:00:01
...
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:401121 (391.7 KiB)
```

So, why don't the counters show correct information?